# Am I calling the function wrong?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working with OOP, and I ran into a problem where when I call the method inside a class by using tkinter command it gives me an error.

I've tried different ways of calling the method but I'm stuck.

```
class ToDoList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tasks = []

    def update_listbox(self):
        self.clear()
        for task in self.tasks:
            box_tasks.insert("end", task)

    def clear(self):
        box_tasks.insert("end", task)

    def add(self):
        task=txt_input.get()
        if task !=" ":
            tasks.append(task)
            self.update_listbox()
        else:
            display["text"]=("Input a task")
```

tkinter command call:

```
add=tk.Button(root, text="Add", fg="DarkOrchid3", bg="blanched almond", command=ToDoList.add)
add.pack(pady=5, ipadx=15)

txt_input=tk.Entry(root, width=25)
txt_input.pack(pady=15)
```

error:

```
TypeError: add() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

This is the error, I understand that it should be defined but I don't really know what it means by it...

Answer (score 1):

`add` is an instance method and you don't instantiate `ToDoList`. If you make an instance of `ToDoList`, you can pass that instance's `.add` method.

```
todo = ToDoList()
add = tk.Button(root, text="Add", fg="DarkOrchid3", bg="blanched almond", command=todo.add)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by creating object for class `ToDoList()`. As class functions can be accessed from object of that class.

```
add=tk.Button(root, text="Add", fg="DarkOrchid3", bg="blanched almond", command=ToDoList().add)
```

Comment: It will create new instance of `ToDoList` every time the button is clicked.  The instance of `ToDoList` should be created once globally.